# Replication Warning: To allow replication of FILESTREAM data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, warnings, replication, merge-replication

I executed a line of script

```
exec sp_addmergearticle @publication = ...
```

and got this warning

> Warning: To allow replication of FILESTREAM data to perform optimally
>   and reduce memory utilization, the 'stream_blob_columns' property has
>   been set to 'true'. To force FILESTREAM table articles to not use blob
>   streaming, use sp_changemergearticle to set 'stream_blob_columns' to
>   'false'.

is it important ?

---

Answer (score 1):

**[ @stream_blob_columns= ] 'stream_blob_columns'**

Specifies that a data stream optimization be used when replicating binary large object columns. stream_blob_columns is nvarchar(5), with a default of FALSE. true means that the optimization will be attempted.

But when you setup replication through SQL Server management studio **using the wizard** on servers where Filestream is enabled stream_blob_columns option is **silently set to true**. The following **warning however is displayed** when creating the replication **via scripts** (which is the recommended method).

**Warning: To allow replication of FILESTREAM data to perform optimally and reduce memory utilization, the 'stream_blob_columns' property has been set to 'true'. To force FILESTREAM table articles to not use blob streaming, use sp_changemergearticle to set 'stream_blob_columns' to 'false'.**

[reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2647118)

Comment: Ok, but what does this option *do*?

Comment: Specifies that a data stream optimization be used when replicating binary large object columns.